# Security of hashing a string using unique key in python

Tags: python, encryption, hash, hashlib

I'd like a method of hashing an email (just the address) using a unique key. So the flow would be the next one:

- I receive an email address.
- I am using that key (along with a hashing algorithm) to hash the email, and then I store that hash in the DB
- If the same email will try to sign in, the same hash method will be applied but it will match the existing one in the database. If it's a new email, store again the hash in DB and so on.

Now, I know about `hashlib` and its basic implementation:

```
import hashlib

email = 'email@domain.com'
key = '1234'
hash_object = hashlib.sha256(email)
print(key + hash_object.hexdigest())
```

Now, I don't know how secure is this implementation as it's always adding `key` in front of my hash.

My wish is to have a unique key (which will be stored somewhere), and always hash an email using it. More, I don't want to ever decode that hash. I'm just interested in encoding it.

Any ideas ?

Comment: So you want add [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to the hash?

Comment: If that salt can be used with a unique key, then yes.

Comment: I think that you're doing right, but don't use a key like that.

Comment: no collision has (yet) been found for sha256. your approach should work. the addition of a salt is usually used for passwords (when you want the same password to result in a different digest). i would not use it in your case. but why not just use a unique incrementing primary key?

Comment: Whatever key I would use, someone can figure out that for all the emails the first `x` chars are the same, so the key is already compromised

Comment: @hiroprotagonist `why not just use a unique incrementing primary key` could you be more specific ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a key *in front of your hash* does nothing. It won't improve security since you're hashing plain password (with no salt) so it'd be very easy to brute force.

What you want is to add a random *salt*. Then you can do the following

```
import random, hashlib
from string import ascii_letters

salt= ''.join(random.shuffle(ascii_letters))
hash=hashlib.sha512(salt+':'+password).hexdigest()
```

Of course, your goal is to add a random combination of letters in front or in the end of the password, so you can generate it in any other way, not necessarily to `shuffle` the whole alphabet.

Comment: The questioner is on python 3, so please use `from string import ascii_letters` instead `from string import letters`.

Comment: @ForceBru it would be easy to find the salt if it would just be: `salt='somestring'` not a random combination of letters ?

Comment: @Alexander, that depends on the length and complexity of your salt. To my mind, it's more secure to use random salts instead of 'static' ones.

Comment: @ForceBru please replace `salt= ''.join(random.shuffle(letters))` to  `salt= ''.join(random.shuffle(ascii_letters))`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as accepted as this is what I wanted. Anyway, as hiro said `no collision has (yet) been found for sha256` so adding a static key won't bother me.

Comment: why random ? use time, insert data to key :)

Comment: @KevinGuan, oh I still can't get used to Python 3 differences from Python 2, thanks again